# formula in text and distance between lines

Tags: math-mode, symbols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{lem}
    Test test test test test teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeetst
    test test test test teset test $\sum \limits_{j=1}^i X_j$

\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

Because of the limits of the sum the distance between lines gets bigger than \setonehalfspacing. 
A possilble solution is `\sum_{j=1}^i X_j`, but this does not look so good. Another way is to use `\textstyle \sum_{j=1}^i X_j`. Then the sum sign gets shorter. What would you do in such a case?

Comment: You can use `$\smash{\sum \limits_{j=1}^i X_j}$`. However, I am not convinced that this looks great.

Comment: The remedy is simple: *Do not* use `\limits` for inline-math sums. For that matter, why not just write `sum_j X_j`? By the way, the `\textstyle` directive is redundant.

Comment: It is important that upper index is j. Ok then there is no possible way except not using limits

Comment: $\smash{\sum \limits_{j=1}^i X_j}$. This does not look better. But I apreciate your advice

Comment: Using `\limits` here  completely negates the design of TeX inline math mode. The _reason_ tex distinguishes inline math from display math is so that it can move the limits to subscript position and avoid disturbing the line spacing.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: you are asking to put an elephant in a suitcase.  There are always two ways, you either squash the elephant or get a bigger suitcase. What answer do you want? You need to compress the mathematics or increase the linespacing or use `\smash` and just hope they don't over-print in this case. Mathematical publications would almost certainly always use the default inline math setting here and preserve the line spacing (actually they wouldn't be using the increased onehalfspacing either so the need to compress the math layout is even more important.

Comment: How can I compress?   You mean I leave limits out and have no probems with line spacing.

Comment: Yes in many papers the spacing is not increased but that would make my problem even worse.

Comment: yes I mean take the default layout for \sum which is explicitly designed to address this problem.